# Unable to write to UserProfile path (no permissions)

Tags: c#, file

I have this code:

```
var path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile);
File.Create(path);
```

However, I get this error:

> Additional information: Access to the path 'C:\Users\MyUsername' is denied.

I tried it with

```
string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile);
```

But the same thing happens

It is not being run as an administrator however it should not need permission to write to the user file, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're calling `File.Create` with a directory...

Comment: @JohnRasch Whoops... Thanks. If you make that an answer I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess it is not about access permissions.

It looks like you are trying to create a folder which already exists using `File.Create` and getting "Access denied".

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to create a directory. Not a file. You can use Directory.CreateDirectory to create a directory if that's what you want.